# How to navigate to a different content page after a function is called

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, content-pages

I have an app that has 2 tabs in Xamarin forms (iOS side). I'd like to know how to make my app navigate to a different content page after a function is called. Let me show you what I mean in code:

these are my two functions in my content page:

```
 protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            TakePhotoButton_Clicked();
        }

        async void TakePhotoButton_Clicked()
        {
            if (App.pictureTaken) return;
            App.pictureTaken = true;

            //Allows users to take pictures in the app
            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                DisplayAlert("No Camera", "Camera is not available.", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                //Sets the properties of the photo file 
                SaveToAlbum = true,
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
                DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear
            });

            if (file == null)
                return;
        }
```

After calling the TakePhotoButton_Clicked() I'd like to force my app to navigate to my other content page.

in pseudocode it would look like:

NavigateTo(MyOtherContentPage);

But im not sure how that would work or if something like that exists. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

If **Root page** of **MainPage** is **NavigationPage** , such as: `MainPage = new NavigationPage (new Page1Xaml ());` , you can use  `Navigation.PushAsync` to navigate to another page as follow :

```
async void OnNextPageButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Navigation.PushAsync (new Page2Xaml ());
}
```

Else if **Root page** is a normal Page, you can use model naivgation method to navigate to another page as follow:

```
async void OnItemSelected (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync (detailPage);
  }
}
```

More info can refer to [Performing Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#performing-navigation) and [Pushing Pages to the Modal Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal#pushing-pages-to-the-modal-stack).

Comment: This makes sense! I did run into one problem though. Although it does navigate to my content page with the code above, it doesn't display my tabs anymore. I want my user to be able to hit the tab button for the camera, and when they are done using the camera, the control return back to the previous tab. do you know how i coulda accomplish this?

Comment: for example: i have a tab called "upload" and a tab called "camera" after the user hits the camera tab and is finished with taking a picture, i need the control to return to the "upload" tab.

Comment: @izzyk Okey , sorry for not understanding the `tab` your said. Do you mean the `tab` is the `TabItem` of `TabbedPage`? You can share a screenshot to expalin that.